# wp_logout_url() not redirecting the user

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am writing a plugin that will redirect the user after logout. If the user provides a link then redirect the user to that place else use the default URL. Here is the code I use.

```
echo esc_url(wp_logout_url( ud_logout_redirect() ));
```

Here is the ud_logout_redirect() function.

```
function ud_logout_redirect() {
        $redirect_link = '';
        $logoutOption = isset( ud_redirection_options()['logout_link_redirect'] ) ? ud_redirection_options()['logout_link_redirect'] : null;
        if (  ! $logoutOption == null ) {
            $redirect_link = apply_filters( 'filter_ud_logout_redirect', $logoutOption);
        }

        return $redirect_link;
    }
```

If the user doesn't provide a link the `example.com` will be default but the `wp_logout_url()` doesn't redirect the user. But it redirects the user to `wp-login.php`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect another site, you have to add that domain in `allowed_redirect_hosts` filter. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'ud_logout_redirect' );

function ud_logout_redirect( $allowed ) {
    $allowed[] = 'multisiteparent.com';
    return $allowed;
}
 
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( 'http://multisiteparent.com' ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

To know more check this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/

Comment: Thanks for your time. The redirection will take place within the site. I forgot to mention that will update the question